# Complex Analysis: Topology and Analysis in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

How can one show that a set $A$ of complex numbers is bounded if and only if, given $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$, there exists a real number $M$ such that $z \in N(z_0;M)$ for every $z \in A$? ($N(z_0;M)$ denotes an open disc)

Comment: This is just a definition of boundedness of a set $A\subset\mathbb{C}$. In words it just means that $A$ is bounded if I can draw an open ball around the whole set $A$ regardless of what point $z_0\in\mathbb{C}$ I draw the ball around. i.e. there exists a finite radius $0<M<\infty$ such that $A\subset N(z_0,M)$ for all $z_0\in\mathbb{C}$.  So if $A = \{1/n : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, then taking the ball around $z_0 = 0$ and radius $M > 1$ does the job.

Answer (score 0):

$A$ is defined to be bounded if $\exists M \in \mathbb{R}_+$ such that $\forall z\in A$ $|z| < M$. If you choose an open disk of radius $r \ge M$, it is clear that any $z$ in $A$ will also be in this disk. (Write down the definition of the disk if this is not clear.)